# How to wire and use a B10K linear LED potentiometer?

Tags: led, analogread, potentiometer

I've bought some nice looking LED potentiometers from Ebay. They look like [this](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=b10k%20potentiometer&espv=2&biw=1270&bih=701&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM7-TM26DLAhUBOJoKHT3hAAUQ_AUIBygC#tbm=isch&q=b10k%20potentiometer%20linear%20led&imgrc=XY_E0nFmWPaxzM%3A).
I'm very new to low level electronics/hardware and I don't know how to wire it. It has 4+2 pins.
Also, how to use it in the Arduino?

Comment: Can't tell.  You need to use a DMM to discover which pins are which. Then https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/AnalogInput

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Taiwan Alpha [spec sheet page 2](http://www.taiwanalpha.com.tw/english2014/p_e_086.htm) for this type of pot shows a little information about the pinout.  Refer to the second “P.C.B. MOUNTING HOLE DETAIL” diagram, which apparently shows the top side PCB layout.  The LED's anode is at lower right, marked B; its cathode is lower left, marked E.  It doesn't say what L (the pin next to E) is.  The three numbered pins most probably are: 1 and 3, ends of the resistive element.  2, wiper.

If that is correct, you could attach pin 1 to 5V, pin 3 to ground, and pin 2 to an analog input.  Before hooking it up like that, however, take ohmmeter readings from pin 1 to pin 2 as you move the slider from one end to the other and see if readings change proportionately to position.

Note, the phrase “Center Dent” on the ebay page probably should instead be “Center Detent” or  “Center Click”.